# Finding an entry which contains all elements of an array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

my current database structure is that I have places that consist of many tags. I want to be able to search for a place that contains all the tags that a user enters into a searchbox. My current code looks like this, and it will only find places which have atleast one of the tags specified:

```
tags = params[:tags]

Place.find(:all, :include => [:tags], :conditions => ['tags.title IN (?)', tags])
```

Comment: The relational operator you require is [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29), popularly known as ["the supplier who supplies all parts"](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/772076.htm). Ask your business analyst or domain expert whether you should be looking at [exact division or division with remainder](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) and how to handle an empty divisior (e.g. do all suppliers supply and empty parts list?).

Comment: It kinda sounds like you're looking for relation division (http://luhong.wordpress.com/2006/03/05/relational-division-in-sql/). This will probably turn into ugly and mostly unreadable code. Otherwise, you could define a named scope (or a scope if you're on rails3) and just iterate over the tags and filter out places that don't match all the tags. This might however cause ActiveRecord to actually execute the SQL query several times, which probably isn't what you want, since it might slow down your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tags = params[:tags]

Place.find(:all, :include => [:tags], :conditions => ['places.id IN
  (SELECT place_id FROM 
    (SELECT place_id, count(place_id) AS tags_count FROM places_tags WHERE tag_id IN
      (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE title IN (?))
    GROUP BY place_id) AS count_table
   WHERE tags_count = ?)', tags, tags.size])
```

Explanation: First find all tags in array, then count how many times each place is found (which equals how many of the tags are matched), then pick out only the places which have all the tags matched.

Answer (score 0):

IF you're using tags and Ruby on Rails, I strongly recommend [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on).

This will let you do things like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Alias for <tt>acts_as_taggable_on :tags</tt>:
  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_taggable_on :skills, :interests
end

@user = User.new(:name => "Bobby")
@user.tag_list = "awesome, slick, hefty"      # this should be familiar
@user.skill_list = "joking, clowning, boxing" # but you can do it for any context!
@user.skill_list                              # => ["joking","clowning","boxing"] as TagList
@user.save

@user.tags # => [<Tag name:"awesome">,<Tag name:"slick">,<Tag name:"hefty">]
@user.skills # => [<Tag name:"joking">,<Tag name:"clowning">,<Tag name:"boxing">]

@frankie = User.create(:name => "Frankie", :skill_list => "joking, flying, eating")
User.skill_counts # => [<Tag name="joking" count=2>,<Tag name="clowning" count=1>...]
@frankie.skill_counts
```

Very easy to implement. And you won't have to worry as much about how to find specific elements in an array.